# Tortoise SVN linking single file to multiple path

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have a file that is to be placed in two different folders. Every time, I make an update to the file, I have to copy the file to the other path also and then commit to the repository. Is there a way in Tortoise SVN to make a sort of a link, like copy to a single path and commit to repository. The other folder should automatically grab the latest version that is linked to the path?

Comment: As far as I know, Tortoise can't do this; it only cares about the existing files/folders and their contents. You could always try creating a [hard link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which will give you the behavior you're looking for at the filesystem level.

Answer (score 1):

If file must be placed in different folders inside common repository, you have to use svn:externals -  one file is real file, second - link to first file

Read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html)!